# QGIS connection to PostGIS showing wrong TYPE

Tags: qgis, postgis

I've got a user that it trying to edit his polygon layer but gets a message `PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)` When you have a look at his PostGIS connection details, the TYPE reads as polygon but if I log as an administrator into PostGIS via QGIS and edit the same layer i dont get an error message but see the TYPE as multipolygon.

I'm not sure where the error lies, in PostGIS or with QGIS not updating itself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem,

in PostGIS I hadn't given the user the `SELECT` privileges in the geometry_columns table in the public schema.